# Java re run jar file

Tags: java, jar

I wanna re-run a jar file from its own (with some additional parameters). How can I do this?
I need the solution to be OS independent.

Comment: It's very hard to glean what you want from what you write. Could you expand a little?

Comment: Actually, I'm developing a client-server like application. All the clients and servers are implemented in a single jar file. Based on argv, the main function runs a server or a client. For debugging purposses I wanna write an specific main function which runs some of the services and some of the clients in different processes. Therefore, I need to rerun my Jar with various arguments.

Comment: You could write a python script to run the jar? That's platform independent?

Comment: Why do you need to rerun the whole jar? Can't you run the individual methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I deciphered the question correctly, we are talking about command line interface arguments. For this there's plenty tutorials: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html

The code is simple, like you said yourself:

```
if ("-server".equalsIgnoreCase(argv)) {
    // we are server
} else if ("-client".equalsIgnoreCase(argv)) {
    // we are client
}
```

Now, depending on how you want to execute you program from the OS, there's a number of ways:

```
$java -jar yourjar.jar -client
```

Or

```
$java -cp yourjar.jar com.your.program.Main -client
```

Same for the "-server".

To run them together, either run them from separate terminal windows (or cmd prompts). Or - if in Linux - you can use ampersand:

```
$java -jar yourjar.jar -client &
$java -jar yourjar.jar -server &
```